# What will the recursion tree of Fibonacci series look like?

Tags: fibonacci-numbers, recursive-algorithms

I am watching the [Introduction to algorithm video](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-046j-introduction-to-algorithms-sma-5503-fall-2005/video-lectures/lecture-3-divide-and-conquer-strassen-fibonacci-polynomial-multiplication/), and the professor talks about finding a Fibonacci number in $\Theta(n)$ time at point 23.30 mins in the video.

1. How is it $\Theta(n)$ time?
2. Which case of the [master theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem) does it fall under?
3. What would the recursion tree look like if we try to use a divide and conquer approach?

P.S:  I know pretty much what the $\Theta(n)$  notation means, so please write your answer accordingly.

Comment: Do you mean $\Theta(n)$? I've never heard of small-theta time.

Comment: yes exactly . small theta time has no meaning since Θ gives a tight bound. I will edit .

Comment: In question (3), do you mean the algorithm he discussed earlier where he computed $fib(n)$ recursively using $fib(n) = fib(n-1)+fib(n-2)$? If you do, I'll add a sample picture to my answer.

Comment: See my latest edit to see how to get big-theta in LaTeX.

Comment: It seems, to get $T(n) = \Theta(n)$, you'll have to use memoization or better yet just pass on the previous calculations to the next recursive call. Otherwise, the recursion tree will get exponentially big. See [here](http://www.fortystones.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/08/fibonacci-recursion-tree.png) for a look at the repeated calculations for fib(5).

Comment: @RickDecker Yes I was referring to the same algorithm. Are you going to put a recursion tree ? That would be helpful here .

Comment: See my edited answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What he's doing is using a simple example of what's known as *dynamic programming*, where one computes a function $f(n)$ by working up from the bottom to get to the desired result. Specifically, to compute $fib(n)$, the $n$-th Fibonacci number, he's doing this

```
fib(n)=
   if (n <= 1)
      return n
   else
      old = 0, prior = 1, next
      for i = 2 to n
         next = old + prior
         old = prior
         prior = next
      return next
```

To see this in action, we compute $fib(4)$, which we know is $3$:

```
i  old  prior  next
2   0     1      1    (compute next = old + prior)
2   1     1      1    (shift everything to the left)
3   1     1      2    (compute next again)
3   1     2      2    (shift again)
4   1     2      3    (and so on...)
4   2     3      3
```

How long does this algorithm take? No need for the Master Theorem here: we have an algorithm that consists, essentially, of a loop, so assuming you can add in constant time, this will have running time $T(n) = \Theta(n)$.

(Actually, this won't work at all on real machines, since $fib(n)$ grows so fast that the numbers will quickly exceed the size of an integer. For example, $fib(2500)$ is 523 decimal digits long, so we'd need to implement some big integer package to do the addition and assignment statements, increasing the run time of this algorithm.)

---

The recursion tree for the original (terrible) recursive algorithm looks like this, when computing $fib(4)$:

[image]

For example, the first call, to $fib(4)$, requires two recursive calls, to $fib(3)\text{ and }fib(2)$. Notice how inefficient this is: just to compute $fib(4)$ we needed nine function calls. In fact, this is a classic example of when *not* to use recursion, especially since there are vastly more efficient ways to do this porblem.

Answer (score 1):

I have to say I know very little about algorithms, but for your second question I did a quick search to see if that theorem even applies to the Fibonacci sequence.

According to [this link](https://web.archive.org/web/20140223135825/http://www.cs.toronto.edu/~fpitt/20079/CSC236/lectures/LN06.txt):

> - Master Theorem does NOT apply to Factorial or recursive Fibonacci,
>     because their runtimes do not satisfy the appropriate type of
>     recurrence.

---

*(Added later, after the link died)*

Here is the relevant snippet from the link, which was a set of notes in a computer science course. It can be seen with this [Wayback link](https://web.archive.org/web/20140223135825/http://www.cs.toronto.edu/~fpitt/20079/CSC236/lectures/LN06.txt)

Since then, it looks like the notes have been relocated to [this location](http://www.cs.toronto.edu/~vassos/b36-notes/notes.pdf) and are more grammatical now. I think the new version of what I was citing starts around page 81 of these notes. It's a little disturbing though that I can't find "Master theorem" referenced by name via a simple text search.

Comment: thats okay . I was also thinking about the same but wasn't sure . But how Θ(n) ?

Comment: Your link is dead. Could you update it, please?

Comment: @MaksimDmitriev Done.

Comment: @Geek, Not Found. The requested URL /~fpitt/20079/CSC236/lectures/LN06.txt was not found on this server.

Comment: @MaksimDmitriev I had hoped you would read the post and click either of the fixed links, but I guess I didn't bother moving the original link. I did this also, and now you can't go wrong. Regards.

Comment: @rschwieb, I'm sorry. I didn't read the whole post, just clicked the link